# Recursive Tree Traversal, returning a variable for each leaf of the tree

Tags: c, pointers, tree, tree-traversal, huffman-code

I have a huffman binary tree. I need to traverse down the tree till I get to each leaf, and for each leaf, I need to "save" a member of that leaf node, and keep all those variables in an array outside of the tree.

Let's say I have this tree:

```
            3\65

        6\-1

            3\70

    9\-1

            2\66

        3\-1

            1\67
16\-1

    7\68
```

Each leaf (7/68, 1/67, 2/66, 7/70, 3/65) has a member called "encoding", which is a string.

(i.e. each node has a node->left, node->right, and node->encoding)

Let's say the encodings are as follows:

```
7/68 got an encoding of 0
1/67 got an encoding of 100
2/66 got an encoding of 101
3/70 got an encoding of 110
3/65 got an encoding of 111
```

I can traverse the tree and print off these values relatively easily, but what I need to do is save these strings in an array outside of the tree.

I can't think of how to save these outside of the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "save these strings in an array outside of the tree."

Comment: Are you sure that you have to store the strings? It is much cleaner if you just store the integers and create the strings after the recursion is finished.

OK, either way (and without giving the sourcecode away) you just:

- create a large enough(*) array before you start the recursion
- create a pointer which will be used for writing into different parts of the array, initialize that pointer to the start of the array.

Give a pointer to that pointer into your recursion as a new/additional function-argument. Every time a leaf is reached in the recursion you

- write into the pointer what you found at the leaf
- increase the pointer (you can do that because you have *the pointer to the pointer*

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember, in huffman code implementation you don't have to use an external array. The easiest way to implement it is adding another pointer ('next') to your struct.
Each element is linked twice. Once as a member of the tree, and once as a member of a linked list.
This way there is no new structure required.